Why can't we ask questions about services related to bitcoin?
I recently asked a question asking if there were any websites that provided stats on bitcoin tx fees (Has anyone created a webpage that shows average price per byte for a tx at different times of day and days of the week?) and the question was closed under the guise that it was soliciting "reviews", which it was not.
Can anyone shed any light on this? Should the question have been closed? If so, should the wording of the explanation be changed, given that it was not soliciting reviews?

Thank you for bringing this up. I voted to reopen the question, because I agree that the reason given does not apply to your question.
Bitcoin Stackexchange has been getting a lot of low-quality content lately especially with the price rally (we're flooded with questions about lost wallets). Perhaps, users are a bit too quick with close votes lately.
